# Splitting a column by taking the right four characters

Tags: r

I would like to split a column into two. I want to take the right 4 numbers and make it its own column.  For example - I have a column with `"New York 2014"` and I want to make two new columns with `"New York"` and `"2014"`.

Please note, I cannot simply delimit on `" "` because some other observations have no space or more than one blank space.

Comment: Look at `?substr` and `?nchar`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your column is data$V1

```
require(stringr)
data$V2 = str_sub(data$V1, 1, -5)
data$V3 = str_sub(data$V1, -4, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table` and `gsub`

```
library(data.table)
info = data.table(
    x = c(
        "New York 2014",
        "New York 2015",
        "New York 2016",
        "Fargo 2014",
        "Fargo 2015",
        "Fargo 2016",
        "San Francisco 2014",
        "San Francisco 2015",
        "San Francisco 2016"
    )
)

##
info[ , c('city','year'):=list( 
    gsub('(\\D+)\\s+(\\d+)','\\1',x), 
    gsub('(\\D+)\\s+(\\d+)','\\2',x)
)]

> info
                    x          city year
1:      New York 2014      New York 2014
2:      New York 2015      New York 2015
3:      New York 2016      New York 2016
4:         Fargo 2014         Fargo 2014
5:         Fargo 2015         Fargo 2015
6:         Fargo 2016         Fargo 2016
7: San Francisco 2014 San Francisco 2014
8: San Francisco 2015 San Francisco 2015
9: San Francisco 2016 San Francisco 2016
```

Don't use `:=` if you don't want to keep column `x`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tstrsplit` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, setNames(tstrsplit(x, '\\s(?=\\d{4}$)', 
             perl=TRUE), c('City', 'Year'))]
#               City Year
#1:         New York 2014
#2:          Houston 2012
#3: Lake Havasu City 2016
```

---

Or a `base R` option would be to create a delimiter between the City and Year using `sub` and then read with `read.table`

```
read.table(text=sub('(\\D+)\\s(\\d+)', '\\1,\\2', 
     df$x),sep=",", header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, 
        col.names=c('City', 'Year'))
#              City Year
#1         New York 2014
#2          Houston 2012
#3 Lake Havasu City 2016
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(x = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L), 
 .Label = c("Houston 2012", 
"Lake Havasu City 2016", "New York 2014"), 
class = "factor")), .Names = "x", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```